# Using a intent to pass the paths of files, but how to get the path of each file in the other activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, path

Using this code to pass the paths of some files, but my problem is how to get on the other activity,each path one by one ?

Thank you.

```
            ArrayList<Uri> files3 = new ArrayList<Uri>();

            for (int i = 0; i < thumbnailsselection.length; i++) {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                    File file = new File(filePaths.get(i).getPath());
                    files3.add(Uri.fromFile(file));

                }
            }

                Intent intentmove = new Intent(getActivity(), Main.class);
                intentmove.putExtra("files", files3.toString());
                startActivity(intentmove);
```

Comment: what is the type of `files3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first Activity,

```
Intent intentmove = new Intent(getActivity(), Main.class);
intentmove.putParcelableArrayListExtra("files", files3);
startActivity(intentmove);
```

And in next activity,

```
ArrayList<Parcelable> uris =
        getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("files");
for (Parcelable p : uris) {
    Uri uri = (Uri) p;
}
```

Comment: Yes mdg5435, that is what i´m doing. The problem is if are 3 files on "files", how can i slip that path to treat each one separately........

Comment: Can you share what value you are passing to `files3`

Comment: files3 = {ArrayList@830053966992}  size = 3
 0 = {Uri$HierarchicalUri@830053967240} "file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/Sent/IMG-20160913-WA0001.jpg"
 1 = {Uri$HierarchicalUri@830053967592} "file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/Sent/IMG-20160913-WA0005.jpg"
 2 = {Uri$HierarchicalUri@830053967872} "file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/Sent/IMG-20160913-WA0015.jpg"

Comment: Are you sure `files3` type is `Uri`? From this `files3 = {ArrayList@830053966992}` value, the type is `ArrayList`... Am i right? Please, post full code of activity in the question.

Comment: Give me this :  cannot resolve method getParcelableArrayList

Comment: Updated the answer. Check now.

Comment: get it..........have to be: getParcelableArrayListExtra    Thanks mdg5435

Answer (score 0):

pass them as an Array of Strings.

```
intentmove.putExtra("files", ** Array of Files goes here **);
```

Get them with:

```
getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("files");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code is second activity

```
 String path1=getIntent().getStringExtra("file1");
 String path2=getIntent().getStringExtra("file2");
 String path3=getIntent().getStringExtra("file3");
```